# Can GCC compile and run a source code without generating object or executable files?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, cross-platform

Can GCC compile and run a source code without generating any output file (neither object nor executable), in a manner that is supported cross-platform? Especially, a solution supported by GCC directly.

I want to avoid generation of any trace file since that is a minor code in a big project. It just messes up the bin directory.

An existing question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738082/), provides a solution for **compiling** source code without generating any output file, such as:

```
gcc somefile.c -o /dev/null
```

However, this only compiles, and doesn't run.

Another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457040/how-to-write-a-program-in-c-such-that-it-will-delete-itself-after-execution) provides a solution that is specific to Windows OS, not cross-platform.

Comment: you mean object file ?

Comment: @Jagannath I want to avoid any binary or object file. Just want to run what is supposed to be built.

Comment: lol. Binary is what it's support to be built and run.

Comment: @ar2015 What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Pradhan I have a cpp file inside a project. I don't want it mess the directory with adding new files. I also prefer avoid `/tmp` as it is no cross OS compatible.

Comment: It sounds like you want to get this to run without leaving any trace that the file exist. Is that your goal?

Comment: @NichoDiaz Yes. you are right.

Comment: `gcc somefile.c -o /dev/null` also genrates compiled and linked executable but `/dev/null` discards all data written  to it.

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia however, `/dev/null` does not run the executable nor is it cross OS compatible.

Comment: @ar2015 Why do you want to run it in the first place? Why wouldn't the syntax check mentioned in the linked question suffice? If the only thing you want to control is the location where the binary is built(for example, outside your source directory), there will be a solution specific to your build system.

Comment: What if after the program is executed it deletes the compiled file?

Comment: @Pradhan I am sure that the source has no error and it is a small minor code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457040/how-to-write-a-program-in-c-such-that-it-will-delete-itself-after-execution

Comment: @NichoDiaz Thank you very much. It does the job. However, i do not delete the question just in case there is any gcc based solution.

Comment: Cool ill post the answer than so you can accept.

Comment: You could use the idea that @NichoDiaz pointed to, along with [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove). Looks like that might be more platform independent.

Comment: [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/JIT) is internally doing that, at least on Linux. Actually it is generating temporary files and removing them.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it. Give the real motivations and some context. Do you care about trace debug files or about temporary executables?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I prefer avoid generating any file and no change on disk. I don't have aim of using tracing of debug files too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to compile and run the C / C++ program and then remove the compiled file, you should add a function to delete the program after it is executed.

Here is a link to an example of a program that deletes itself. 
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457040/how-to-write-a-program-in-c-such-that-it-will-delete-itself-after-execution)

Comment: OP talked of  portability. Is this portable ? On Windows can we delete something that's in use ?

Comment: Yes this works on Windows, I updated with an example.

Comment: Please don't plagiarize — give credit where credit is due!

Comment: I don't really think it needs to be there, And I did give it credit, if you read the comments I clearly refer the OP to the link that answer is posted. There I deleted it for you.

Comment: The comments are fungible; they can be removed at any time.  The answer is where the credit should be given.

Answer (score 3):

In your case (you want to avoid cluttering the build tree), a practically useful solution might be to have some *convention* about temporary executables.

For example, you could decide that every intermediate executable or file is named `*.tmp` or `_*` or `*.tmpbin` (for temporary binaries) and have some `Makefile` rules which removes them. Or you could use [mktemp(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mktemp.1.html) in your `Makefile` to get a temporary file name. Don't forget to remove it later.

Also, most big projects have a compilation step and an installing step (often `make install`); and if you don't have that you probably should. You want your installing step to avoid installing the temporary binaries or files; with some naming convention this is quite simple: the first command for `install` phony target in your `Makefile` would remove these temporary binaries or files.

Also, you generally build in a file tree different of the final `bin/` directory, so you could leave the temporary executables in the build tree.

As several people noticed, removing its own executable is easy on Linux (do a [readlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) on `"/proc/self/exe"` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details) then [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) the result of `readlink`....) but difficult on Windows.

So practically your question is not a very important issue.... (if you use suitable build conventions). And [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) work on *files* (because it will run `ld` internally to build that executable file); however [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit) is hiding them. AFAIK, you won't even be able to use `/dev/stdout` as the executable output of `gcc` (but you can run `gcc -x c /dev/stdin` to compile C code from *stdin*). So **GCC cannot avoid making an executable *file*** (but you could have it temporary, or in a [*tmpfs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) file system or a [*FUSE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) one). So you need something external to your `gcc` command (perhaps simple an `rm` in some following line of your `Makefile`) to remove the produced executable.

You could also decide to have ([dynamically loaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading)) [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29) (e.g. use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) on Linux). Your main program could load a plugin (with  `dlopen` on Linux) - perhaps even after having generated dynamically its C++ code and having compiled that generated code into e.g. some [shared object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries) `.so` on Linux (or some [DLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) on Windows), as I [do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15142988/841108) in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) -, run functions in it obtained with `dlsym`, and unload the plugin (with `dlclose` on Linux) and finally `remove` it. You might use cross-platform frameworks like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) to avoid dealing with OS specific plugin code.

Comment: Thanks Basil for your answer. However it is very important for me to hear if it is possible by GCC directly or not. I don't know why people avoid talking about it. Even saying `No` does not make me annoyed. But at least I know that I should not continue searching for it.

Comment: I think the problem is not compilation on wind, but running a generated executable file on the wind.

Answer (score 3):

A simple bash script might help:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'compile... ' $1
gcc $1 && ./a.out && rm a.out
```

supposed it's named `once`, then you can do

```
$ sh once any.c
```

to compile `any.c` and just run it **once**.
You can also make `once` executable with `chmod +x once` so you can just type

```
$ once any.c
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

For c `gcc/g++ filname.c && ./a.out && rm a.out`

For c++ `g++ filename.cpp && ./a.out && rm a.out`

Comment: Not sure why you repeat an unaccepted answer but thanks.