# Is it possible to NOT make symbols from my executable available to dynamically opened libraries?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, dynamic-loading

When I `dlsym()` some library, all the global symbols from my main executable can be accessed if referenced in the code of the library.

How can this be avoided? At least no flag for `dlsym()` seems to offer such feature.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Archlinux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making all symbols in your main executable hidden by default.  That is, compile with `-fvisibility=hidden` and possibly more options as described here: [How to apply gcc -fvisibility option to symbols in static libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222162/how-to-apply-gcc-fvisibility-option-to-symbols-in-static-libraries)

This should make your main executable export no symbols, so there will be nothing for the library to find.