# Symbol visibility not working as expected

Tags: c, linker, clang

I have a sample program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if 1
#define FOR_EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility("hidden")))
#else
#define FOR_EXPORT
#endif

FOR_EXPORT void mylocalfunction1(void)
{
    printf("function1\n");
}

void mylocalfunction2(void)
{
    printf("function2\n");
}

void mylocalfunction3(void)
{
    printf("function3\n");
}

void printMessage(void)
{
    printf("Running the function exported from the shared library\n");
}
```

And compile it using

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -o libdefaultvisibility.so defaultvisibility.c
```

Now after compilation I do:

```
$ nm libdefaultvisibility.so
nm libdefaultvisibility.so 
0000000000000eb0 t _mylocalfunction1
0000000000000ed0 t _mylocalfunction2
0000000000000ef0 t _mylocalfunction3
0000000000000f10 t _printMessage
                 U _printf
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Which means as far as I can tell that despite `-fvisibility=hidden` all symbols get exported. The book I was following claimed that only the function marked with `FOR_EXPORT` should be exported.

I looked oup several other resources, but for the simple test I'm doing `-fvisibility=hidden` should be sufficient.

My clang version:

```
$ clang -v
clang -v
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: I believe you want the command `nm -gCD libdefaultvisibility.so | grep ' T '`, not `nm libdefaultvisibility.so`. Possible duplicate of [How to apply gcc -fvisibility option to symbols in static libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2222162/608639)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the output of `nm`. Scroll through `man nm` and you'll you
read that the `t` flag means the symbol is a local (static) symbol in
the `text` section. The linker can't see it. If it were global (external)
the flag would be `T`. So all four of your functions are local.

Contrast:

```
$ clang -shared -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -o libdefaultvisibility.so defaultvisibility.c
$ nm libdefaultvisibility.so | grep ' t '
0000000000000570 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000000600 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000200e08 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000000640 t frame_dummy
0000000000200e00 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000000670 t mylocalfunction1
0000000000000690 t mylocalfunction2
00000000000006b0 t mylocalfunction3
00000000000006d0 t printMessage
00000000000005b0 t register_tm_clones
```

with dropping the `-fvisibility=hidden`:

```
$ clang -shared -fPIC -o libdefaultvisibility.so defaultvisibility.c
$ nm libdefaultvisibility.so | grep ' t '
0000000000000600 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000000690 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000200e08 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
00000000000006d0 t frame_dummy
0000000000200e00 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000000700 t mylocalfunction1
0000000000000640 t register_tm_clones
$ nm libdefaultvisibility.so | grep ' T '
0000000000000780 T _fini
00000000000005b0 T _init
0000000000000720 T mylocalfunction2
0000000000000740 T mylocalfunction3
0000000000000760 T printMessage
```

Then only the explicitly hidden `mylocalfunction1` remains local, and the
other three are now global.

You should not expect that a symbol marked with `__attribute__ ((visibility("hidden")))`
will be exported by a shared library in any circumstances. The attribute means precisely
that it will *not* be, whether it is applied explicitly to a symbol, as in this case,
or acquired by default in the presence of the linker option `-fvisibility=hidden`.

If you want to export just that one function in the example by means of a `visibility` attribution
you would have:

```
#define FOR_EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
```

Then:

```
$ clang -shared -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -o libdefaultvisibility.so defaultvisibility.c
$ nm libdefaultvisibility.so | grep ' T '
0000000000000720 T _fini
0000000000000550 T _init
00000000000006a0 T mylocalfunction1
```

It is global, because the explicit attribition overrides the commandline option,
and all your other functions are local. Perhaps confusingly, `default` visibility
is always *public*.

And you could accomplish this without resorting to `visibility` attributions - which are
not portable - simply declaring all the functions that you *don't* want to export as `static`. Then the compiler
would not expose them to the linker in the first place:

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mylocalfunction1(void)
{
    printf("function1\n");
}

static void mylocalfunction2(void)
{
    printf("function2\n");
}

static void mylocalfunction3(void)
{
    printf("function3\n");
}

static void printMessage(void)
{
    printf("Running the function exported from the shared library\n");
}
```

With which you get again:-

```
$ clang -shared -fPIC -o libfoo.so foo.c
$ nm libfoo.so | grep ' T '
00000000000006c0 T _fini
0000000000000550 T _init
00000000000006a0 T mylocalfunction1
```

Although the distinction does not make itself felt in your example you
should understand that while a local/static symbol is not seen by the linker and (therefore) is unavailable for *dynamic* linkage, a global/external symbol
*may or may not* be available for dynamic linkage. `visibility`
controls the availability of global symbols for *dynamic* linkage, only.

Comment: Thank you, indeed i misunderstood the output of `nm`, especially with regards to `T` vs `t`. It actually worked as expected. The book I'm reading is fairly brief on how to interpret the output of `nm` and therefore I wasn't really sure what I was looking at. This answer cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to [GCC Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) on Visibility, you should:

> Use `nm -C -D` on the outputted DSO [*Dynamic Shared Object*] to compare before and after to see
>   the difference it makes.

As stated on `nm` manual:

> -D will display the dynamic symbols rather than the normal symbols

If I compile your code exactly as you did I get the following objects:

```
$ nm -C -D libdefaultvisibility.so
nm -C -D libdefaultvisibility.so
0000000000200a68 B __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000200a68 D _edata
0000000000200a70 B _end
00000000000006c8 T _fini
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000518 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
                 U puts
```

And if I compile it without the `-fvisibility=hidden` option I get the objects:

```
$ nm -C -D libdefaultvisibility.so
nm -C -D libdefaultvisibility.so
0000000000200ae8 B __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000200ae8 D _edata
0000000000200af0 B _end
0000000000000748 T _fini
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000000005a0 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000000712 T mylocalfunction2
0000000000000724 T mylocalfunction3
0000000000000736 T printMessage
                 U puts
```