# How to rename functions in android ndk library

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, obfuscation

guys. I want to change function names that I import from static lib, like ProGuard does it with java methods and classes. I think it can make reverse much harder. For example, if I check some file with sha1 I don't want the reverser to know what this function exactly is. He can see some func0024 instead.

Is it possible to make this with standard tools in android cmake? Or if it's not what tools can you advise for this task?

Comment: You're building static libraries that you link into a shared library, and then you load that shared library in your app..? The names of the functions in your static libraries should already be gone in the shared library, unless you're shipping the unstripped library with your app for some reason.

Comment: i check binary from apk with readelf and it show me unchanged openssl function names.

Comment: Try adding `-fvisibility=hidden` to your `LOCAL_CFLAGS` and `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` to your `LOCAL_LDFLAGS`. And make sure you're running `readelf` on the stripped .so file (i.e. not the one in `obj/local`).

Comment: I build project with cmake. Is it what you mean?
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL")`
It does not work

Comment: I check binary directly from apk with objdump -d

Comment: The second flag is intended for the linker, so it should probably be added to `STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS` rather than `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Comment: I'm sorry, just opened wrong apk. It helped me. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to Michael's answer you should add this line to your CMakeLists.txt file

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL")`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222162/how-to-apply-gcc-fvisibility-option-to-symbols-in-static-libraries for more details.