# Duplicate symbol defined in a dll import library in MinGW build

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw-w64

I have static library `libA-static` that defines function `privateFunction` and is linked into library `libB-static`. `libB-static` implements a lot of stuff but exports only one function `publicFunction`. `libB-static` is then linked into shared library  `libC-shared` that re-exports `publicFunction`. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222162/how-to-apply-fvisibility-option-to-symbols-in-static-libraries) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649735/how-to-link-static-library-into-dynamic-library-in-gcc), I compile all libraries with `-fvisibility=hidden`, label public with default visibility and link `libB-static` to `libC-shared` as whole archive.

My main program depends on `libC-shared` and `libA-static`. The setup works fine on Linux, Mac (and on Windows too), but on MinGW linking fails with multiple definitions of symbol `privateFunction`. The second definition comes from the import library `libC-shared.dll.a`. The size of import library is ridiculous for a single exported symbol (10MB) and it looks like it contains at least entire `libB-static`.

I tried linking `libC-shared` with `-Wl,--exclude-libs,All`, and the size of import library in this case is 1 KB, but `publicFunction` is then unresolved. I also tried linking `libC-shared` with `-Wl,--exclude-libs,libB-static`, but in this case linking of `libC-shared` fails to resolve `privateFunction`.

This is the linking command generated by CMake, where `libC-shared=GraphicsEngineOpenGL-shared`, `libB-static=GraphicsEngineOpenGL-static` and `libA` is all other static libs:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X86_64~1.0-P\mingw64\bin\G__~1.EXE    -shared -o GraphicsEngineOpenGL-shared.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libGraphicsEngineOpenGL-shared.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\GraphicsEngineOpenGL-shared.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,--whole-archive libGraphicsEngineOpenGL-static.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive ../GLSLTools/libGLSLTools.a ../HLSL2GLSLConverterLib/libHLSL2GLSLConverterLib.a ../GraphicsEngine/libGraphicsEngine.a ../GraphicsAccessories/libGraphicsAccessories.a ../../Common/libCommon.a ../../Platforms/Win32/libWin32Platform.a ../../Platforms/Basic/libBasicPlatform.a -lShlwapi ../../Primitives/libPrimitives.a ../../External/glew/libglew-static.a -lopengl32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

My main problem is obviously linking error, but ridiculous size of the import library is probably the key to the answer.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  For example, the C++ allows overloading of functions and some compilers use *name mangling* to manage the overloading.  This may interfere with libraries built by compilers that use different schemes of name mangling.

Comment: The language is c++. In either case I don't understand why definition of a hidden function could end up in the import library.

Comment: You should update your tags.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Removed c tag