# how to strip symbols from an object file and then archive as .a

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am trying to strip the symbols so that we can distribute our code to external developers without disclosing our functionality. We are in the process of hiding our symbols so that when we issue nm command, the symbols shud not be visible. The idea is to give a static library with all the symbols hidden except for very few ones. I am able to create a shared library with all the symbols stripped. But i am unable to get it for a static library. I tried following the below link but was unsuccessful,

[Symbol hiding in static libraries built with Xcode/gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276474/symbol-hiding-in-static-libraries-built-with-xcode-gcc)

I have two files file1.c and file2.c and file1.c makes a function call to file2.c. I want to hide the some  symbols in file2.c. If I use the ld -r option, i am still able to see the symbols when i use nm command. I have tried using the **attribute**((visibility("hidden"))) before the function which I want to hide. Can anyone please tell me the exact steps to get a .o file which will have the symbols stripped but internally linked.

Comment: You're aware that the symbols for the public interface must remain intact, correct?

Comment: To explain on the earlier comment: the symbols used between the objects of the library must stay visible, or they cannot be resolved at the link time. If you insist on hiding, you can put all library source in one translation unit (and deliver just the object) or deliver a dynamically linked library.

Comment: What you're planning, is going to make debugging a nightmare, glad I won't have to use or support it!

Comment: Don't down-vote a question just because you are philosophically opposed to what he is trying to do.  It's perfectly reasonable to want to protect the intellectual property in your binary from reverse engineering.

Answer (score 3):

"nm" command shows you symbols, You can use strip command to remove symbols....
see man page of strip command...