# Why is it impossible to hide symbols from Objective-C object files?

Tags: objective-c, macos, linker, symbols

I am writing a small dynamic library that uses Objective-C and exposes C-linkage functions to Unity (it's a native plugin).

Even though my compiler settings has *Symbols Hidden by Default* set to *Yes*, and I am using `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` on the function declarations I want to expose, even `static` symbols (both functions and global variables) appear in the output library.

I have recreated a [test Xcode project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18450868/HiddenSymbolTest.zip), which initially contained a C file

file.h:

```
#pragma once

extern __attribute__((visibility("default"))) void not_hidden();
```

file.c:

```
#include "file.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static void hidden()
{
    printf("I'm hidden\n");
}

void not_hidden()
{
    printf("I'm not hidden\n");
    hidden();
}
```

and this works as advertised:

```
$ nm libHiddenSymbolTest.dylib 
0000000000000f40 T _not_hidden
                 U _printf
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

However as soon as I add an Objective-C file with similar functions (`not_hidden2()`, etc), then all `static` symbols are likewise exposed:

```
$ nm libHiddenSymbolTest.dylib 
                 U _CFStringGetCStringPtr
                 U _NSLog
00000000000054d0 s _OBJC_METACLASS_$___ARCLite__
                 U __Block_copy
                 U __DefaultRuneLocale
0000000000005710 b __ZGVZL18add_image_hook_ARCPK11mach_headerlE7patches
0000000000005830 b __ZGVZL22add_image_hook_swiftV1PK11mach_headerlE7patches
0000000000005640 b __ZGVZL30add_image_hook_autoreleasepoolPK11mach_headerlE7patches
0000000000004160 s __ZL11_class_name
00000000000039a4 t __ZL12cxxConstructP11objc_object
00000000000055d0 d __ZL12demangleLock
000000000000377a t __ZL13demangledNamePKcb
0000000000002ab3 t __ZL13replaceMethodP10objc_classP13objc_selectorPFP11objc_objectS4_S2_zEPS6_
0000000000005748 b __ZL14NSString_class
00000000000035b0 t __ZL14initialize_impP11objc_objectP13objc_selector
0000000000001aa2 t __ZL15__ARCLite__loadv
0000000000003927 t __ZL16scanMangledFieldRPKcS0_S1_Ri
00000000000041a8 s __ZL17_load_method_name
00000000000043d0 s __ZL17_load_method_type
0000000000003461 t __ZL17transcribeMethodsP10objc_classP15glue_class_ro_t
00000000000022b9 t __ZL18add_image_hook_ARCPK11mach_headerl
00000000000035b6 t __ZL18allocateMaybeSwiftP18glue_swift_class_tm
0000000000001f7f t __ZL19patch_lazy_pointersPK11mach_headerP7patch_tm
00000000000034e5 t __ZL19transcribeProtocolsP10objc_classP15glue_class_ro_t
00000000000039d4 t __ZL20fixStringForCoreDataP11objc_object
0000000000003530 t __ZL20transcribePropertiesP10objc_classP15glue_class_ro_t
0000000000002785 t __ZL21__arclite_objc_retainP11objc_object
00000000000025e3 t __ZL21__arclite_object_copyP11objc_objectm
0000000000005740 b __ZL22NSConstantString_class
00000000000027a1 t __ZL22__arclite_objc_releaseP11objc_object
000000000000288f t __ZL22add_image_hook_swiftV1PK11mach_headerl
0000000000003646 t __ZL22copySwiftV1MangledNamePKcb
0000000000005870 b __ZL22original_class_getName
0000000000005848 b __ZL22original_objc_getClass
0000000000005610 b __ZL23NSAutoreleasePool_class
00000000000033dc t __ZL23__arclite_class_getNameP10objc_class
0000000000003230 t __ZL23__arclite_objc_getClassPKc
00000000000054f8 s __ZL24OBJC_CLASS_$___ARCLite__
000000000000248c t __ZL24__arclite_object_setIvarP11objc_objectP9objc_ivarS0_
0000000000005738 b __ZL25NSMutableDictionary_class
0000000000005868 b __ZL25original_objc_getProtocol
0000000000005860 b __ZL25original_objc_lookUpClass
0000000000005878 b __ZL25original_protocol_getName
00000000000027b3 t __ZL26__arclite_objc_autoreleaseP11objc_object
0000000000003384 t __ZL26__arclite_objc_getProtocolPKc
000000000000332f t __ZL26__arclite_objc_lookUpClassPKc
0000000000002797 t __ZL26__arclite_objc_retainBlockP11objc_object
000000000000283f t __ZL26__arclite_objc_storeStrongPP11objc_objectS0_
00000000000033f1 t __ZL26__arclite_protocol_getNameP8Protocol
0000000000005850 b __ZL26original_objc_getMetaClass
00000000000052c8 s __ZL27OBJC_CLASS_RO_$___ARCLite__
0000000000003285 t __ZL27__arclite_objc_getMetaClassPKc
0000000000005758 b __ZL27original_NSKKMS_indexForKey
0000000000002b9a t __ZL28__arclite_NSKKMS_indexForKeyP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorS0_
0000000000002df0 t __ZL28__arclite_objc_readClassPairP10objc_classPK15objc_image_info
0000000000005760 b __ZL28original_NSKKsD_objectForKey
0000000000002bec t __ZL29__arclite_NSKKsD_objectForKeyP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorS0_
0000000000005720 b __ZL29original_NSManagedObject_init
0000000000005718 b __ZL30NSUndoManagerProxy_targetClass
0000000000002ae6 t __ZL30__arclite_NSManagedObject_initP11objc_objectP13objc_selector
0000000000001ecb t __ZL30add_image_hook_autoreleasepoolPK11mach_headerl
000000000000399e t __ZL30arclite_uninitialized_functionv
0000000000005858 b __ZL30original_objc_getRequiredClass
0000000000005280 s __ZL31OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$___ARCLite__
00000000000032da t __ZL31__arclite_objc_getRequiredClassPKc
0000000000005838 b __ZL31original_objc_allocateClassPair
0000000000005840 b __ZL31original_object_getIndexedIvars
0000000000005310 s __ZL32OBJC_$_CLASS_METHODS___ARCLite__
000000000000313d t __ZL32__arclite_objc_allocateClassPairP10objc_classPKcm
00000000000027c5 t __ZL32__arclite_objc_retainAutoreleaseP11objc_object
00000000000031de t __ZL32__arclite_object_getIndexedIvarsP11objc_object
0000000000005770 b __ZL32original_NSKKsD_setObject_forKey
0000000000002c92 t __ZL33__arclite_NSKKsD_setObject_forKeyP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorS0_S0_
0000000000001f6d t __ZL33__arclite_objc_autoreleasePoolPopPv
0000000000001f54 t __ZL34__arclite_objc_autoreleasePoolPushv
0000000000005768 b __ZL34original_NSKKsD_removeObjectForKey
0000000000002c3e t __ZL35__arclite_NSKKsD_removeObjectForKeyP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorS0_
0000000000005730 b __ZL35original_NSManagedObject_allocBatch
0000000000002b0c t __ZL36__arclite_NSManagedObject_allocBatchP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorPS0_S0_j
0000000000002434 t __ZL36__arclite_object_setInstanceVariableP11objc_objectPKcPv
0000000000005750 b __ZL36original_NSKKMS_fastIndexForKnownKey
0000000000005880 b __ZL36original_objc_copyClassNamesForImage
0000000000002b48 t __ZL37__arclite_NSKKMS_fastIndexForKnownKeyP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorS0_
00000000000027f0 t __ZL37__arclite_objc_autoreleaseReturnValueP11objc_object
0000000000003409 t __ZL37__arclite_objc_copyClassNamesForImagePKcPj
0000000000005778 b __ZL40original_NSKKsD_addEntriesFromDictionary
0000000000005728 b __ZL40original_NSManagedObject_allocWithEntity
0000000000002cfb t __ZL41__arclite_NSKKsD_addEntriesFromDictionaryP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorP12NSDictionary
0000000000002af9 t __ZL41__arclite_NSManagedObject_allocWithEntityP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorS0_
00000000000021e7 t __ZL42__arclite_NSArray_objectAtIndexedSubscriptP7NSArrayP13objc_selectorm
0000000000002a7a t __ZL42__arclite_NSUndoManagerProxy_isKindOfClassP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorP10objc_class
0000000000002802 t __ZL43__arclite_objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValueP11objc_object
000000000000282d t __ZL44__arclite_objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValueP11objc_object
000000000000225b t __ZL46__arclite_NSDictionary_objectForKeyedSubscriptP12NSDictionaryP13objc_selectorP11objc_object
000000000000226d t __ZL47__arclite_NSOrderedSet_objectAtIndexedSubscriptP12NSOrderedSetP13objc_selectorm
00000000000021f9 t __ZL53__arclite_NSMutableArray_setObject_atIndexedSubscriptP14NSMutableArrayP13objc_selectorP11objc_objectm
0000000000002291 t __ZL58__arclite_NSMutableDictionary__setObject_forKeyedSubscriptP19NSMutableDictionaryP13objc_selectorP11objc_objectS4_
000000000000227f t __ZL58__arclite_NSMutableOrderedSet_setObject_atIndexedSubscriptP19NSMutableOrderedSetP13objc_selectorP11objc_objectm
0000000000005888 b __ZL9Demangled
0000000000005650 b __ZZL18add_image_hook_ARCPK11mach_headerlE7patches
0000000000005780 b __ZZL22add_image_hook_swiftV1PK11mach_headerlE7patches
0000000000005620 b __ZZL30add_image_hook_autoreleasepoolPK11mach_headerlE7patches
                 U ___CFConstantStringClassReference
                 U ___stack_chk_fail
                 U ___stack_chk_guard
                 U __dyld_register_func_for_add_image
0000000000005260 s __non_lazy_classes
                 U __objc_empty_cache
                 U __objc_empty_vtable
                 U _asprintf
                 U _bzero
                 U _calloc
                 U _class_addMethod
                 U _class_addProperty
                 U _class_addProtocol
                 U _class_getInstanceMethod
                 U _class_getInstanceSize
                 U _class_getInstanceVariable
                 U _class_getIvarLayout
                 U _class_getName
                 U _class_getSuperclass
                 U _class_isMetaClass
                 U _class_replaceMethod
                 U _class_respondsToSelector
                 U _free
                 U _hash_create
                 U _hash_search
0000000000001a30 t _hidden
0000000000001a70 t _hidden2
                 U _ivar_getName
                 U _ivar_getOffset
                 U _kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber
                 U _malloc
                 U _memcmp
                 U _memcpy
                 U _method_setImplementation
0000000000001a00 T _not_hidden
0000000000001a50 T _not_hidden2
                 U _objc_allocateClassPair
                 U _objc_autoreleasePoolPush
                 U _objc_collectingEnabled
                 U _objc_constructInstance
                 U _objc_copyClassNamesForImage
                 U _objc_getClass
                 U _objc_getMetaClass
                 U _objc_getProtocol
                 U _objc_getRequiredClass
                 U _objc_initializeClassPair
                 U _objc_lookUpClass
                 U _objc_msgSend
                 U _objc_readClassPair
                 U _objc_registerClassPair
                 U _objc_retain
0000000000001a87 T _objc_retainedObject
0000000000001a90 T _objc_unretainedObject
0000000000001a99 T _objc_unretainedPointer
                 U _object_getClass
                 U _object_getIndexedIvars
                 U _object_getIvar
                 U _object_setIvar
                 U _printf
                 U _property_copyAttributeList
                 U _protocol_getMethodDescription
                 U _protocol_getName
                 U _pthread_mutex_lock
                 U _pthread_mutex_unlock
                 U _sel_getUid
                 U _strcmp
                 U _strlen
                 U _strncmp
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Note that I have left the various *strip symbols* settings to their default, and this appears to be OK for C-file symbols as shown in the first `nm` output, above.

Can anyone explain why that is, and perhaps suggest a way to hide the Objective-C symbols I don't want exposed?

Update: I am using Xcode 7.0.1 on OSX 10.11.0.

Update #2 (more experimentation):

1. Including a `.m` file in the project causes Xcode to stop passing `-fvisibility=hidden` during compilation of the `.c` file, thereby ignoring the *Symbols Hidden by Default* build setting.  To repeat; before adding the `.m` this was being passed to the compiler.
2. Setting the *Exported Symbols File* to a file containing `_not_hidden` and `_not_hidden2` has no effect whatsoever.

It seems to me that ignoring *Symbols Hidden by Default* is the root cause of the issue so I experimented with explicitly setting `__attribute__((visibility("hidden"/"default")))` (via a preprocessor macro) on every single function and variable and it has no effect either.  So that seems to implicate the linker.

Comment: Post the entire symbol table that is shown, or tell us what your concern is.

Comment: OK, edited.  Not sure why though...

Comment: Note that despite the `hidden` functions appearing when you add ObjC code, they are marked `t` which means local. The `not_hidden` functions are marked `T`, which means global. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3276474/269753

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons why you are still seeing a bunch of symbols in your `dylib`:

**1. The strip mode you have set (or don't) isn't getting everything it's capable of.**

(Try adjusting the strip styles in the build settings, generally removing `debugging symbols` is fine, however, I've bumped it up to `Non-Global Symbols` for this purpose, which is likely about as far as you can take it. Your dylib likely won't compile if you decide to strip `all symbols`, and it would essentially render it unusable at that point)

[image]

**2. Some Objective-C symbols are absolutely required.**

(These include any of the `objc` variety, and others such as `class`, `property`, `object`, etc. since they are all supporting the runtime, and yes there can still be quite a few present)

**3. You are possibly looking at the debug version of your dylib and not the release version.**

(Make sure you are looking at the ***release*** version of your `dylib`. That would be `Product > Archive` > `Export`. It should then be nicely stripped of most of the symbols that are not actually being used.

---

You might need to play around with the strip settings a bit, although just using the settings that I've shown above [resulted in approximately 100+ fewer symbols](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/06288abd162065c0ff9e) than currently show in your dump. It's really not bad to have symbols included in your file, in fact if there's ever a problem then it's all the more helpful. It's understandable though if you want to remove irrelevant or unused symbols that just clutter things up.

Comment: Why does the version of the project with just the C-source file work as expected then and things change drastically only when I start using Objective-C?

Comment: Visibility controls apply only to the C or C++ subset of your code, however, they do not apply to Objective-C classes and methods. Objective-C class and message names are bound by the Objective-C runtime, not by the linker, so the notion of visibility does not apply. There is no mechanism for hiding an Objective-C class or method defined in a dynamic library from the clients of that library.

Comment: OK, I have accepted your answer as stripping the non-global symbols is the solution to the problem.  A further issue I faced, however, was getting the linker to actually perform the stripping (see my answer, below).

Answer (score 1):

OK, stripping the non-global symbols does solve the issue, however I was unable to set the correct sequence in the *Deployment* section of the *Build Settings* (I tried many different combos).

The only way I could force the linker to remove non-global symbols was to add this to the *Other Linker Flags*:

```
-Xlinker -x
```

Comment: Most of the "strip" build settings are not used unless Deployment Postprocessing is enabled. For example, see the [docs for `STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW4) and note its "companion" `DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING`. See the docs for that where it explains more clearly that it's a prerequisite for the former.

Comment: @KenThomases That's good information, thanks.  Presumabely any post-processing will destroy the code signing of the `.dylib`?  If so, it's less than useful that this is the case.

Comment: That's odd, because I get the same exact result with/without the flags.